# php mySQL insertion issue

Tags: php, mysql

Do you see something wrong in this insertion??

It does not work for me..

```
$insSubm = "INSERT INTO cR_Submissions memberID ='".$memberID."', RefNumb='".$RefNumb."', title ='".$title."', CopyRightNumb='".$copyRightNumbWork."', type='".$natureTypeWork."', OtherTitle='".$alternateTitleWork."', OwnershipTransfer='".$textareaPrior."', Status ='".$status."', DateWhen='".$todaydate."', Time='".$NowisTime."'";
$resultinsSubm=mysql_query($insSubm) or die("Error insert Submissions: ".mysql_error());
```

Am I blind?

Please help

Thanks

Comment: What's the `mysql_error()` returning? Also note you are using the alternate `INSERT` syntax, which may not be supported in your version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's invalid SQL syntax. The SQL syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, ..., fieldN) VALUES (val1, val2, ..., valN)
```

An alternative MySQL syntax for this is:

```
INSERT INTO table SET field1 = val1, field2 = val2, ..., fieldN = valN
```

You're missing the `SET` keyword. Check out the [`INSERT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) documentation for more about this.

Answer (score 0):

Query should be something like...

```
$insSubm = "
  INSERT INTO `cR_Submissions` (`memberID`, ...)
  VALUES ('" . $memberID . "', ... )";
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code with the following code:

```
$insSubm = "INSERT INTO cR_Submissions (memberID, RefNumb, title, CopyRightNumb, type, OtherTitle, OwnershipTransfer, Status, DateWhen, Time) 
            VALUES ('$memberID', '$RefNumb', '$title', '$copyRightNumbWork', '$natureTypeWork', '$alternateTitleWork', '$textareaPrior', '$status', '$todaydate', '$NowisTime');";

$resultinsSubm = mysql_query($insSubm) or die("Error insert Submissions: ".mysql_error());
```